# Gimp: is there a way to combine shortcuts?

Tags: gimp, shortcuts

I'm recording a video screencapturing Gimp, and there are a few different tools I use, like drawing with a pencil at a given brush size, erase at a different size, add new layer, and delete the current layer.

I've found the `Configure Keyboard Shortcuts` editor under the `Preferences` and I could configure some shortcuts, so that everything can be done using the keyboard.

Since I'm recording a video, I want to use as few key presses as possible.

For example when I'm drawing with a pencil then I want to erase, I need to select the eraser (1 keypress), then increase the size (2 keypresses). When I want to switch back, I select the pencil (1 keypress), and reset the size back (1 press to reset, 1 or 2 to increase).

Is there a way to define "composite" shortcuts, that simply press a series of shortcuts for me, so that I only need to press 1 key?

I'm using Ubuntu with Gnome3.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

The closer you get in current GIMP is being able to write a plug-in, that shows up in the menus, and therefore can have a single shortcut.  Some of my answers on GIMP have full instructions on how to create such plug-ins, but it is a way different procedure than just using the program.

Comment: Could you give me some pointers where should I look? I've tried writing a Script fu script, and I could set the brush size with the [gimp-context-set-brush-size](https://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/libgimp/libgimp-gimpcontext.html#gimp-context-set-brush-size), but I was unable to change the selected tool to Pencil.